# Does Gyrator change phase of wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

I have read that gyrator changes direction of polarization of linearly polarized wave. But then it is also given that phase is also changed. How are two related? I understand due to faraday rotation plane of polarization is changed but how that leads to change of phase?

Comment: When you say gyrator, are you referring to the hypothetical 5th type of electronic component? I thought you might be, then I stumbled over the reference to polarisation change. Do you mean polarity? Could you clarify.

Comment: https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Gyrator#:~:text=a%20directional%20phase%20shifter%2C%20a,modulators%2C%20circulators%2C%20and%20switches.
I also read it from. It is a device which causes phase shift of 180 in one direction and 0 in other direction.